# Musica no slide jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um slideshow, estou tentando que a cada div de id Content seja tocado a musica em questão dentro da div content.
Estava pensando em usar um if ($("#Content1").is(":visible") {$('#1.mp3').play();}  Porém procurei na net como fazer isso más não encontrei nada parecido :(
Muito obrigado pessoal. Stackoverflow SHOOWWW! :)
OBS: Codigo abaixo esta tocando as 2 musicas juntas.

```
<div class="slide">
    <div class="content-switcher" id="Content1">
        <img src="imagem"/>
                <span class="pe-7s-volume">
                    <audio id="playTune" autoplay>
                        <source src="2.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </span>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="content-switcher" id="Content2">
        <img src="img/2botao.jpg" style="height:100%;" />
                <span class="pe-7s-volume">
                    <audio id="playTune" autoplay>
                        <source src="1.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </span>           
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo assim resolve seu problema?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#showContent1").click(function() {    
    showContent("Content1")
  })

  function showContent(id) {
    if (!$("#" + id).is(':visible')) {
      $("#Content1").show()
      $("#" + id + " audio")[0].play()
    } else {
      $("#" + id).hide()
      
    }
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="showContent1">show content1</button>
<div class="slide">
  <div class="content-switcher" style="display:none" id="Content1">
    <img src="imagem" />
    <span class="pe-7s-volume">
                                    <audio controls="">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
                </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-switcher" id="Content2">
  <img src="img/2botao.jpg" style="height:100%;" />
  <span class="pe-7s-volume">
                  <audio controls="">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
                </span> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse trecho de codigo salvou o final de semana que tive de dor de cabeça tentando achar uma solução. Obrigado amigo Marco. :)